# Merge multi-dimensional array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have an array in php like this :

`$temp = array(
    'vpc1' => array(
       'reg1' => array (
           'sub1',
        )
    )
    'vpc2' => array(
        'reg1' => array (
             'sub2',
        )
    )
    'vpc1' => array(
        'reg1' => array (
             'sub3',
        )
    )
);`

I have to merge the values to get output as :

```
`$temp = array(
'vpc1' => array(
   'reg1' => array (
       'sub1',
       'sub3',
    )
)
'vpc2' => array(
    'reg2' => array (
       'sub2',
    )
)
```

);`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you any code you have been testing?

Comment: The structure of your data suggests a deeper problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking for help?

Comment: I'm new to php didn't knew about the structure. Thanks for help. It helped a lot  to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is your incoming data structure in $temp1. Think about your data and make it atomar. Thats why some boy give u "-1 vote" ... I think its just a question. I voted your question up again.

```
 <?php 

//u got this
$temp1 = array("vpc1 | reg1 | sub1", "vpc1 | reg1 | sub2", "vpc1 | reg1 | sub3");
//u want this
$temp2 = array("vpc1 | reg1 | sub1,sub2,sub3");

//u need this, cause thats why we use arrays in complex data structures.
$temp = array(
    'vpc1' => array(
       'reg1' => array (
           'sub1',
           'sub2',
           'sub3',
        )
    )
);

//ugly bug working
foreach ($temp1 as $data) {
    $parts = preg_split("/\|/", $data);

    // most ugly part in it. Thats where you guys should think about your data again.
    $temp[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]]; 
}

var_dump($temp);

// array (size=1)
//     'vpc1' =>
//         array (size=1)
//         'reg1' =>
//             array (size=3)
//                 0 => string 'sub1' (length=4)
//                 1 => string 'sub2' (length=4)
//                 2 => string 'sub3' (length=4)

?>
```